# Attempting to connect my smart contract with my front end

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, dapps, dapp-development

I am attempting to build a basic DAO program. My smart contracts are mostly finished and my front end is mostly finished except for of course the blockchain elements. Before I jump into my current problem I will preface this by saying this is my first ever dApp, I am absolutely sure I will run into many more problems and if anybody could look over my 'DAOContext' file and let me know which pieces need to be changed/replaced it would be very, very appreciated.

Currently I am trying to display information from my 'Governor' smart contract in my 'ProposalCard' component and running into the following error:

```
Server Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title') at:
  20 | <div className="flex flex-row font-semibold">
> 21 |     {Proposal.title}
     |              ^
  22 | </div>
```

Here is my 'Proposal Card' file where the error is generated:

```
import React from 'react'
import Image from 'next/image';
import Link from 'next/link';
import images from '../assets';

import { DAOContext } from '../context/DAOContext';

const ProposalCard = ({ Proposal }) => {
  return (
    //<Link href={{ pathname: }} Link to the modal
    <div className="w-full p-5 rounded-[10px] border-[0.5px] border-nft-gray-1 dark:border-nft-gray-2 bg-[#fdfdfd] dark:bg-nft-black-3 drop-shadow-sm dark:drop-shadow-xl">
        <div className="flex flex-row">
            <div className="flex-1 justify-start">
                <Image src={images.logo02} classname='w-20' alt='logo' />
            </div>
            <div className="flex-4 justify-end">
                Open or Closed
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-row font-semibold">
            {Proposal.title}
        </div>
        <div className="">
            Description
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProposalCard;
```

Here is my 'DAOContext' file which I am using to connect my Smart contracts with my front end:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Web3Modal from 'web3modal';
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import axios from 'axios';

import { GovernorTokenAddress, GovernorTokenAddressABI, GovernorAddress, GovernorAddressABI } from './constants';

const fetchGovernorContract = (signerOrProvider) => new ethers.Contract(GovernorAddress, GovernorAddressABI, signerOrProvider);
const fetchGovernorTokenContract = (signerOrProvider) => new ethers.Contract(GovernorTokenAddress, GovernorTokenAddressABI, signerOrProvider);

export const DAOContext = React.createContext();

export const DAOProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [currentAccount, setCurrentAccount] = useState('');
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);


    const checkIfWalletIsConnected = async () => {
      if (!window.ethereum) return alert('Please install Metamask');
  
      const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_accounts' });
  
      if (accounts.length) {
        setCurrentAccount(accounts[0]);
      } else {
        console.log('No accounts found');
      }
    };


    useEffect(() => {
      checkIfWalletIsConnected();
    }, []);


    const connectWallet = async () => {
      if (!window.ethereum) return alert('Please install Metamask');
  
      const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
  
      setCurrentAccount(accounts[0]);
  
      window.location.reload();
    };


    const FetchProposals = async () => {
      setIsLoading(false);
  
      const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider();
      const contract = fetchGovernorContract(provider);
  
      const data = await contract.fetchProposals();
  
      const items = await Promise.all(data.map(async ({ proposer, addressTo, proposalID, startingTime, tokenAmount: unformattedTokenAmount, votesYes, votesNo }) => {
        const { data: { title, description } } = await axios.get(tokenID);
        const tokenAmount = ethers.utils.formatUnits(unformattedTokenAmount.toString(), 'ether');
  
        return { title, proposer, addressTo, proposalID, startingTime, tokenAmount, votesYes, votesNo, description };
      }));
  
      return items;
    };


    const CreateProposal = async (formInput, router) => {
      const { title, tokenAmount, addressTo, description } = formInput;

      if (!title || !tokenAmount || !addressTo || !description) return;

      try {
        await CreateProposal(addressTo, tokenAmount, description);
        router.push('/');
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };


    const SubmitVote = async (Vote, Proposal) => {
      const web3Modal = new Web3Modal();
      const connection = await web3Modal.connect();
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection);
      const signer = provider.getSigner();
      const contract = new ethers.Contract(GovernorAddress, GovernorAddressABI, signer);

      const _SubmitVote = await contract.submitVote(Vote, Proposal.proposalID);
      setIsLoading(true);
      await _SubmitVote.wait();
      setIsLoading(false);
    };


    const ProcessProposal = async () => {
      const web3Modal = new Web3Modal();
      const connection = await web3Modal.connect();
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection);
      const signer = provider.getSigner();
      const contract = new ethers.Contract(GovernorAddress, GovernorAddressABI, signer);

      const _ProcessProposal = await contract.processProposal(Proposal.proposalID);
      if (contract.hasVotingPeriodEnded = false) {
        await _ProcessProposal.wait();
      } else if (contract.hasVotingPeriodEnded = true) {
        return _ProcessProposal;
      }
    };


  return (
    <DAOContext.Provider value={{ currentAccount, connectWallet, FetchProposals, SubmitVote, CreateProposal, ProcessProposal }}>
      {children}
    </DAOContext.Provider>
  );

}
```

Here are my two smart contracts, 'Governor' and 'ERC20Basic':

```
/ SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";
import "./nativeToken.sol";

contract Governor is ERC20Basic {

    ERC20Basic public _token;
    address public tokenAddress = address(_token);
    address public contractAddress;
    uint public votingperiod = 6545;

    uint public count;

    uint public contractBalance;
    uint public userBalance;

    mapping(uint => Proposal) proposals;

    event SubmitProposal(address proposer, address addressTo, uint startingTime, uint tokenAmount);
    event SubmitVote(uint proposalID, address voter, uint votesYes, uint votesNo);
    event ProposalProcessed(uint proposalID, address addressTo, uint tokenAmount);

    struct Proposal {
        address proposer;
        address addressTo;
        uint proposalID;
        uint startingTime;
        uint tokenAmount;
        uint votesYes;
        uint votesNo;
    }

    
    constructor(address nativeToken) {
        _token = ERC20Basic(nativeToken);
        contractBalance = _token.balanceOf(address(this));
        userBalance = _token.balanceOf(msg.sender);
    }


    function hasVotingPeriodEnded(uint proposalID) public view returns(bool HasVotingPeriodEnded) {
        if (block.timestamp >= votingperiod + proposals[proposalID].startingTime) {
            return true;
        } else if (block.timestamp < votingperiod + proposals[proposalID].startingTime) {
            return false;
        }
    }


    // Primary Functions

    function createProposal(address _addressTo, uint _tokenAmount) public {
        uint proposalID = count;
        Proposal storage _proposal = proposals[proposalID];
        _proposal.proposer = msg.sender;
        _proposal.addressTo = _addressTo;
        _proposal.startingTime = block.timestamp;
        _proposal.tokenAmount = _tokenAmount;
        _proposal.votesYes = 0;
        _proposal.votesNo = 0;
        count += 1;
        emit SubmitProposal(msg.sender, _addressTo, block.timestamp, _tokenAmount);
    }


    function processProposal(uint proposalID) public returns (bool proposalPassed) {
        require(block.timestamp >= votingperiod + proposals[proposalID].startingTime, "Voting period has not ended yet");
        Proposal storage _proposal = proposals[proposalID];
        if (_proposal.votesYes > _proposal.votesNo) {
            proposalPassed = true;
        } else if (_proposal.votesYes <= _proposal.votesNo) {
            proposalPassed = false;
        }
        if (proposalPassed = true) {
            contractBalance = contractBalance - _proposal.tokenAmount;
            userBalance = userBalance + _proposal.tokenAmount;
        }
        emit ProposalProcessed(proposals[proposalID].proposalID, _proposal.addressTo, _proposal.tokenAmount);
    }


    function submitVote(bool vote, uint proposalID) public {
        require(block.timestamp < votingperiod + proposals[proposalID].startingTime, "Voting period has ended");
        Proposal storage _proposal = proposals[proposalID];
        if (vote = true) {
            _proposal.votesYes = _proposal.votesYes + userBalance;
        } else if (vote = false) {
            _proposal.votesNo = _proposal.votesNo + userBalance;
        }
        emit SubmitVote(proposalID, msg.sender, _proposal.votesYes, _proposal.votesNo);
    }

    function fetchProposal() public view returns(Proposal[] memory) {
        uint currentIndex = 0;
        Proposal[] memory _proposal = new Proposal[](count);
        for(uint i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            uint currentID = i + 1;
            Proposal storage currentProposal = proposals[currentID];
            _proposal[currentIndex] = currentProposal;
            currentIndex += 1;
        }
        return _proposal;
    }


}
```

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface IERC20 {

    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);


    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}


contract ERC20Basic is IERC20 {

    address public _tokenAddress = address(this);

    string public constant name = "GovernorToken";
    string public constant symbol = "GT";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 18;


    mapping(address => uint256) balances;

    mapping(address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;

    uint256 totalSupply_ = 10 ether;


   constructor() {
    balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply_;
    }

    function totalSupply() public override view returns (uint256) {
    return totalSupply_;
    }

    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public override view returns (uint256) {
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }

    function transfer(address receiver, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        require(numTokens <= balances[msg.sender]);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender]-numTokens;
        balances[receiver] = balances[receiver]+numTokens;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, numTokens);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address delegate, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        allowed[msg.sender][delegate] = numTokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, delegate, numTokens);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address delegate) public override view returns (uint) {
        return allowed[owner][delegate];
    }

    function transferFrom(address owner, address buyer, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        require(numTokens <= balances[owner]);
        require(numTokens <= allowed[owner][msg.sender]);

        balances[owner] = balances[owner]-numTokens;
        allowed[owner][msg.sender] = allowed[owner][msg.sender]-numTokens;
        balances[buyer] = balances[buyer]+numTokens;
        emit Transfer(owner, buyer, numTokens);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure if I've missed something, but I can't see were ProposalCard is called, but I notice the Proposal struct doesn't have a title element in it. I'm assuming that is the data structure passed in to ProposalCard ?

Comment: Yes the title and description elements are not supposed to be passed from the contract but simply passed as from a seperate form element as form input which is linked to the corresponding proposal based on its proposalID